# Stored procedure error "ambiguous column"

Tags: sql

hey guys im creating a stored procedure for search form in the asp.net im getting error, code is given below

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_searchcustomervendordetails] 
 @customervendortype varchar(30)=Null,
    @customervendorid   varchar(30)=Null,
    @customervendorname varchar(30)=Null,
    @state              varchar(30)=Null,
    @city               varchar(30)=Null
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
--if @customervendortype is not null and len(@customervendortype)=0 set @customervendortype = null
--if @customervendorid is not null and len(@cuatomervendorid)=0 set @customervendorid = null
--if @customervendorname is not null and len(@customervendorname)=0 set @customervendorname = null
--if @city is not null and len(@city)=0 set @city = null
--if @state is not null and len(@state)=0 set @state = null

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT     CustomerVendorDetails.customervendorid AS CustomerVendorID,CustomerVendorAddressDetails.customervendorname, CustomerVendorAddressDetails.doorno, CustomerVendorAddressDetails.street, 
           CustomerVendorAddressDetails.city, CustomerVendorAddressDetails.state, CustomerVendorAddressDetails.country, 
           CustomerVendorAddressDetails.pincode,  CustomerVendorDetails.decidingauthority, 
           CustomerVendorDetails.landlineno1, CustomerVendorDetails.landlineno2, CustomerVendorDetails.faxno, ContactPersonDetails.contactno, 
           ContactPersonDetails.designation
FROM       CustomerVendorDetails INNER JOIN
           CustomerVendorAddressDetails ON CustomerVendorDetails.customervendorid = CustomerVendorAddressDetails.customervendorid INNER JOIN
           ContactPersonDetails ON CustomerVendorAddressDetails.customervendorid = ContactPersonDetails.customervendorid
WHERE      (@customervendortype is null or customervendortype like @customervendortype)
        or (@customervendorid is null or customervendorid like @customervendorid) 
        or (@customervendorname is null or customervendorname like @customervendorname)
        or (city is null or city like @city)
        or (state is null or state like @city)
END
```

im getting this error

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_searchcustomervendordetails, Line 34
Ambiguous column name 'customervendorid'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_searchcustomervendordetails, Line 35
Ambiguous column name 'customervendorname'
```

can any help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you'll get an "ambiguous column name" error when you're performing a select that joins multiple tables together that have at least one column with the same name, and then you reference that column without prefixing it with the table.

So I your case I would assume that the `customervendorname` column appears in more than one table (perhaps `CustomerVendorDetails` and `CustomerVendorAddressDetails`?) so when you use it in the where clause you'll need to prefix it with the table name.  I see in fact that you've already done this in the list of columns to be selected; you just need to do the same throughout the statement.

Thus

```
WHERE (@customervendortype is null or
       customervendortype like @customervendortype)
```

needs to become

```
WHERE (@customervendortype is null or
       CustomerVendorAddressDetails.customervendortype like @customervendortype)
```

and possibly similar changes for the other constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be in this part:

```
or (@customervendorid is null or customervendorid like @customervendorid) 
        or (@customervendorname is null or customervendorname like @customervendorname)
```

You should check if you have customervendorid and customervendorname columns in your CustomerVendorAddressDetails and ContactPersonDetails tables

Answer (score 0):

(@customervendorid is null or customervendorid like @customervendorid) or (@customervendorname is null or customervendorname like @customervendorname)

check these two lines ..

please post your table structures for customer and other table you are using. It will be easy to guess the error

Answer (score 0):

replace customervendorid  by CustomerVendorDetails.customervendorid and customervendorname by CustomerVendorAddressDetails.customervendorname in where condition will work.